# How to calculate energy from power I receive every 5 minutes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electricity, power

I have to calculate energy from power measurements, which I receive every 5 minutes. The values are summed and assigned to measurements, then monthly measurements and finally yearly measurements. Having that aggregates of power measurements, the question is if I can calculate energy in kWh unit by equation:

$\text{energy} = \text{power_sum} \times  \frac{5}{60} \times \frac 1 {1000}$

as I want to convert 5 min to hours and W to kW.

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your power values are in W *and* if you assume that power consumption is constant over each five minute period then your formula gives your total energy consumption in kWh. Essentially, you are integrating the power consumption values using the rectangle rule.

For a slightly more accurate estimate, you could use the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), which assumes that power consumption varies linearly over each five minute period, instead of remaining constant. If your power values are $P_0$ to $P_n$ every $5$ minutes over a period of $5n$ minutes then your energy estimate becomes

$\displaystyle \text{Energy} = \left[ P_0 + P_n + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} P_k \right] \times \frac 1 {24000}$