# Actual power consumption of an irregular measure (GPU/CPU)

Tags: measurements, power, electronics, electrical-engineering, computer

Hello and my apologies if this is off-topic or really too basic. My math and physic days are really far far away....

I want to measure the energy consumption of both the GPU and CPU of a computer during work, where the load on each component vary greatly from one minute to another (I am doing high-end 3D graphics). I am using OpenHardwareMonitor which gives me a value in watt every second for different components.
So I got a curve with those value for a certain duration.

Am I right to assume that the actual power consumption during this duration is the integral of that curve ? And that for intervals of 1 second, the rectangular rule would be enough to get a correct approximation ? (from [this answer to a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/633047/how-to-calculate-energy-from-power-i-receive-every-5-minutes/633057#633057))

Would I get a reasonable estimation of the power consumption, and are there any problem thatI am not aware of in my process ?

Note : ultimately I am not interested in exact consumption values, but in estamating the relative consumption values of different 3D graphics processes that rely either on the CPU or GPU.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, energy (in joules) use is the integral of power (in watts) over time (in seconds).

Whether OpenHardwareMonitor gives accurate values, I can't say.